# jQuery Trigger Form Submit on Page Load if GET Parameters are set

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to submit the form on my page upon page load if there are certain parameters set in the query string. The form submits using ajax and works fine and the pre-population of the form fields from the query string is fine aswell but no matter what I try to automatically submit the form, I end up in an infinite loop of page loads.

**PHP**

```
// top of page
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['postcode'])) {
        $postcode = trim($_GET['postcode']);
    } else {
        $postcode = '';
    }

    if (isset($_GET['phone_num'])) {
        $phone_num = trim($_GET['phone_num']);
    } else {
        $phone_num = '';
    }
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
/* 
// causing infinite page loads
if ($('input[name="phone_num"]').val() != '' || $('input[name="postcode"]').val() != '') {
    $('#check').trigger("click");
    return false;
}
*/

$('form').submit(function() {
    $.get("script.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        // process results
    }, "json");      
    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" action="" method="get">
    <input class="span2" type="text" name="phone_num" placeholder="Phone Number" value="<?php echo $phone_num; ?>">
    <input class="span2" type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="check">Check</button>
</form>
```

Instead of using a `click` function for the auto form submit I've tried doing the same `$('form').submit` but I get the same problem. I was expecting the page to function as normal so that if the parameters were set then the ajax call would automatically be made but this is obviously not the case.

Comment: why are you triggering a click event to submit a form? why not just... submit the form? Note: that won't fix your problem.

Comment: @KevinB It's just the latest iteration of what I've tried, I have used `$('form').submit` as well as `$('#check').trigger("click");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exiting your code before you bind the submit event. Remove the `return false` in your if statement, then move the if statement to after the submit binding.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.get("script.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        // process results
    }, "json");      
    return false;
});

if ($('input[name="phone_num"]').val() != '' || $('input[name="postcode"]').val() != '') {
    $('#check').trigger("click");
    //return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" action="" method="get">
    <input class="span2" type="text" name="phone_num" placeholder="Phone Number" value="<?php echo $phone_num; ?>">
    <input class="span2" type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="check">Check</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#check').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("script.php", $('form').serialize(), function(data){
        // process results
    }, "json");      
    return false;
});
if ($('input[name="phone_num"]').val() != '' || $('input[name="postcode"]').val() != '') {
    $('#check').trigger("click");
}
```

When using a `submit` button, you are performing the default event (submitting the form) as well as processing the handler of the `.click()` event. To avoid this, use `e.preventDefault();` causing only the scripted portion of the event to process.

Comment: thanks @DevlshOne, that will probably work but I was trying to avoid duplicating the ajax request stuff as it's quite lengthy which is why I omitted it from my post.

Comment: You can still trigger the `.click()` event when your form input criteria has been met.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if($('input[name="phone_num"]').val() && $('input[name="postcode"]').val()) {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $.get("script.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
            // process results
        }, "json");      
        return false;
    }).submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this line on your code.

```
$('form').trigger("submit");
```